# Prove that the action of a Lie group on its Lie algebra via the adjoint representation reads $\mathrm{ad}(g)(X)=g^{-1}Xg$

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I am a physics undergrad.

The adjoint action of a group on itself is $\operatorname{Ad}: G \times G \to G$ is defined to be $\operatorname{Ad}:(g,h) \to g^{-1}hg$. The adjoint representation of the group  is the action of the group on its lie algeba, and is defined as the derivative of this map at the identity element, i.e. $\mathrm{D}\operatorname{Ad}_1=:\operatorname{ad}:G\to\operatorname{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$. How do I prove that for matrix lie groups, this map is actually $\operatorname{ad}(g)(X)=g^{-1} X g $ for $X \in \mathfrak{g}$.

What is the linear map $\operatorname{ad}$ in general?

I am sorry if this question is really trivial, but all the math books are inaccessible to me, and I couldn't find this in any physics book.

Answer (score 8):

Let $c:[0,1]\to G$ be a differentiable curve in $G$ such that $c(0)=1$ (identity matrix).

Then, if $g\in G$, the (group) adjoint action on the points of the curve $c(t)$ is $g^{-1}c(t)g.$ Now every element of the Lie algebra can be written as a tangent vector to some curve $c$ at the identity ($t=0$). 
If $x$ is such tangent vector, that is:
$$
x = \frac{dc(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0},
$$

then the derivative of the group adjoint is:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}g^{-1}c(t)g\bigg|_{t=0} = g^{-1}xg,
$$

by simple Leibniz rules, which is exactly the adjoint action on the algebra.

Comment: This seems to be true for any Lie group. Why does then $\operatorname{ad}(g)(x)=g^{-1}xg$ only hold for matrix Lie groups?

Comment: Because $g^{-1}xg$ is *not* a composition in $G$, $x$ belongs to the Lie algebra.
If they are matrix Lie groups, since group and matrix composition (where defined) coincide, you can write the computations above. 

If the group is not a matrix Lie group, you can still construct the adjoint by deriving $g^{-1}cg$, but notationwise you have to be more careful.
In particular, outside matrices $g^{-1}xg$ makes no sense, unless you define it in some way.